# Overwrite Current Column Value with a Document property using Iron Python

Tags: ironpython, spotfire

Problem:
I am requesting user input through Document Property if they want to change the data.

How do I then replace the current value in the coloumn by the Doc Property value.
It can easily be done in R but then the execution time of the tool increases significantly

Comment: can you please clarify and maybe provide an example? it's not clear what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Is your new column a calc column? If so, you can access and overwrite the 'Expression' attribute with your new Value. Here's some pseudo-code for you. Hope this helps! Otherwise I think you would benefit from adding a little more detail.

```
value = #whatever your Document Property happens to be

tbl_target = Document.Data.Tables['YOUR_TABLE']
target_col = tbl_target.Columns.Item['YOUR_COLUMN']
target_col.Properties.SetProperty('Expression', value)
```